# How do this fit into an article latex

Tags: pgfplotstable, article, preamble

```
\begin{table}[htbp]%\caption{Summary statistics}

    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lS[table-format=-2.8,table-align-text-post=false]@{\,}rS[table-format=-2.6,table-align-text-post=false]@{\,}rS[table-format=-2.8,table-align-text-post=false]@{\,}r@{}}
        \toprule
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}       \\
        \cmidrule(ll){2-3}\cmidrule(ll){4-5}\cmidrule(ll){6-7}
        & {netinmargin}
             & {liqdtyratio}
            & {offdep}
             \\
        \midrule
        GDP & -0.0452* &     -0.00709** &  -0.790*    \\
        roe  &  0.0908***  & 3.961*  & 0.296*  \\
        dbacba      &       -0.0924***& -0.00684* & -0.346*** \\
        dbagdp      &     0.121***&  -0.0191***  &  2.223***   \\
        cbagdp         &       -0.104***   & -0.0112** & \\
        fdgdp        &      0.170***   & 0.0139***  &  \\
        stmktcap     &      -0.0313***  & -0.000374*** & \\
        listco\_pc &    -0.000903***   & 0.0000722*** & \\
        llgdp         &      -0.239***     &      -0.125** &       -1.968***\\
        overhead         &   0.669***                 &       &   \\
        cbagdp         &                   -0.342***&        &   \\
        infltn         &        0.0269**   &       &   \\
        stvaltraded        &      0.175***          &        &   \\
        bcbd         &         -0.00621***  &     &   \\
        ll\_usd         &             -0.00000177***      &   -0.000398***  &  \\
        stmktcap         &               &    &  -0.0154**  \\
        xregcon         &               &  -0.0493*   &    \\
        fdi         &                 &  -0.375  &  \\
        roa         &           &  -5.581***  &  \\
        stturnover         &        9.844***       &  2.668***    &  80.35*** \\
        \_cons         &    -2.028          &  36.10***   &   -0.00571***  \\[2pt]
        \hline \\
        \(N\)       &         116   &          181   &         132   \\
        \(R^{2}\)   &       0.882   &       0.719  &       0.607  \\
        adj. \(R^{2}\)&       0.868  &       0.701   &       0.578   \\
        \midrule[1pt]       \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: please extend your code snippet to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. information of your page layout (text width} is key data for help you. help us to help you!

Comment: @Werner this is not related to mine.

Comment: Why not related? It seems to be the exact same question?

Comment: Just guessing: I think that the true problem is that this code cannot be simply pasted into a existing article. If you edit in short time your question and  explain that this is really the issue, it could be reopened and I have a  detailed answer ready. Basically you need the `siunitx` and `booktabs` in the preamble, plus other changes as the table is actually ugly.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I've found what the problem is, and the O.P. is right: it isn't a problem of a too wide table, but a bad coding problem.. So I'd like to re-open the question, since I have a solution.

Answer (score 3):

**edit:**
considering [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) comments (thank you very much, egreg).

try the following (i assumed one column document):

```
\begin{table}[htbp]%
\caption{Summary statistics}
    \centering
\small
\sisetup{table-space-text-post={***},
         table-align-text-post=false}
% \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l
                   S[table-format=-1.8]
                   S[table-format=-2.8]
                   S[table-format=-1.5]
                @{}}
    \toprule
            &   {(1)}               &   {(2)}               &   {(3)}           \\
            &   {netinmargin}       &   {liqdtyratio}       &   {offdep}        \\
    \midrule
GDP         & -0.0452\sym{*}        & -0.00709**            & -0.790\sym{*}     \\
roe         &  0.0908\sym{***}      &  3.961\sym{*}         &  0.296\sym{*}     \\
dbacba      & -0.0924\sym{***}      & -0.00684\sym{*}       & -0.346\sym{***}   \\
dbagdp      &  0.121\sym{***}       & -0.0191\sym{***}      &  2.223\sym{***}   \\
cbagdp      & -0.104\sym{***}       & -0.0112\sym{**}       &                   \\
fdgdp       &  0.170\sym{***}       &  0.0139\sym{***}      &                   \\
stmktcap    & -0.0313\sym{***}      & -0.000374\sym{***}    &                   \\
listco\_pc  & -0.000903\sym{***}    &  0.0000722\sym{***}   &                   \\
llgdp       & -0.239\sym{***}       & -0.125\sym{**}        & -1.968\sym{***}   \\
overhead    &   0.669\sym{***}      &                       &                   \\
cbagdp      & -0.342\sym{***}       &                       &                   \\
infltn      &  0.0269\sym{**}       &                       &                   \\
stvaltraded &  0.175\sym{***}       &                       &                   \\
bcbd        & -0.00621\sym{***}     &                       &                   \\
ll\_usd     & -0.00000177\sym{***}  & -0.000398\sym{***}    &                   \\
stmktcap    &                       &                       &  -0.0154\sym{**}  \\
xregcon     &                       & -0.0493\sym{*}        &                   \\
fdi         &                       & -0.375                &                   \\
roa         &                       & -5.581\sym{***}       &                   \\
stturnover  &  9.844\sym{***}       &  2.668\sym{***}       &  80.35            \\
\_cons      & -2.028                &  36.10\sym{***}       & -0.00571\sym{***} \\
    \midrule
\(N\)       & {116}         & {181}         & {132\quad}    \\
\(R^{2}\)   & {0.882}       & {0.719}       & {0.607}       \\
adj. \(R^{2}\)
            & {0.868}       & {0.701}       & {0.578}       \\
    \bottomrule      
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

comparison between your and table code will show you difference (number of columns, missing ampersands, formatting columns,...)

in my table testbed i obtain:

[image]

Comment: I'd not align the numbers in the last two rows, because they aren't of the same kind as those in the rows above.

Comment: @eg, you are probably right. i'm not "statistic man" and i just overtake op table. i will correct answer considering your comment. thank you very much!

Comment: Also using `\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\ensuremath{^{#1}}` and `\sym{*}` instead of `*` (and so on) would make smaller asterisks (which is the usual form for statistics tables, as far as I know).

Comment: @egreg, thank you very much for short curse from statistics :-)! i had been used statistic (a lot) but in study/research of stochastic systems, where we don't use/need such tables ...

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never (I want to post this seven hours ago, but then the question was closed): Basically, you only need include also in the preamble the packages `siunitx` and `booktabs`. This produce the table, but the result however is not very nice:

[image: mwe]

The example below show also some fixes in the table as well as other minor changes to improve both the readability of the source code and the final PDF.

[image: mww]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar,textcomp}
\newunicodechar{·}{\textsuperscript{*}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
 \caption{Summary statistics}
 \centering
 \renewcommand\arraystretch{1} % this is the default
 \begin{tabular}{@{}l*3{S[table-format=-3.10,table-align-text-post=false]}@{}}
 \toprule
                & {(1)}             & {(2)}             & {(3)} \\
 \cmidrule(l){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}\cmidrule(l){4-4}
                & {netinmargin}     & {liqdtyratio}     & {offdep} \\
 \midrule
 GDP            & -0.0452·          & -0.00709··        & -0.790· \\
 roe            & 0.0908···         & 3.961$·           & 0.296·· \\
 dbacba         & -0.0924···        & -0.00684·         & -0.346··· \\
 dbagdp         & 0.121···          & -0.0191···        & 2.223··· \\
 cbagdp         & -0.104···         & -0.0112··         & \\
 fdgdp          & 0.170···          & 0.0139···         & \\
 stmktcap       & -0.0313···        & -0.000374···      & \\
 listco\_pc     & -0.000903···      & 0.0000722···      & \\
 llgdp          & -0.239···         & -0.125··          & -1.968···\\
 overhead       & 0.669···          &                   & \\
 cbagdp         & -0.342···         &                   & \\
 infltn         & 0.0269··          &                   & \\
 stvaltraded    & 0.175···          &                   & \\
 bcbd           & -0.00621···       &                   & \\
 ll\_usd        & -0.00000177···    & -0.000398···      & \\
 stmktcap       &                   &                   & -0.0154·· \\
 xregcon        &                   & -0.0493·          & \\
 fdi            &                   & -0.375            & \\
 roa            &                   & -5.581···         & \\
 stturnover     & 9.844···          & 2.668···          & 80.35··· \\
 \_cons         & -2.028            & 36.10···          & -0.00571··· \\
 \midrule
 \(N\)          & 116               & 181           & 132 \\
 \(R^{2}\)      & 0.882             & 0.719         & 0.607 \\
 adj. \(R^{2}\) & 0.868             & 0.701         & 0.578 \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```